# Grok parsing issue using parsing log containing text starting [date] [hostname]

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse below log using grok

```
 [2018-10-06 12:04:03:0227] [MYMACHINENAME]
```

and the grok expression which I used is

```
/[%{DATESTAMP:date}/] /[%{WORD:data}%/]
```

and this expression is not working. I tried to replace WORD with hostname even then it not working and if I try to either of the matchers alone then it works.
Can anyone provide me the better tutorial pages to learn grok expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your pattern.
First off, you escape character using backslash `/` not forward slash `\`. Second, you don't need `%` to match `]` in the end.
Third, `DATESTAMP` doesn't match your date pattern, you need `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601`.

Your final pattern should become,

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\] \[%{WORD}\]
```

Comment: Thank you..How would i get to know to which date pattern it matches?

Answer (score 0):

Regex pattern `DATESTAMP` is not correct for your string. Try using `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601`.

Here you can see all grok regex patterns: [grok-patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).